# Membership stays on Pending after Payment

Tags: wordpress, civimember, payment

I am building a custom plugin to handle Memberships in Wordpress (CiviCRM version 5.50.1). I am using the Order and Payment APIs (version 3 - there doesn't seem to be anything in version 4?) to do this.

My code looks like this for the Order:

```
$params = [
  'membership_type_id' => $price_field_value[0]['membership_type_id'],
  'contact_id' => $contact_id,
  'status_id' => 'Pending',
  'source' => ...,
];

$order_data = [
  'contact_id' => $contact_id,
  'total_amount' => $total_amount,
  'financial_type_id' => $settings['civicrm_contribution_financial_type'],
  'payment_instrument_id' => $settings['civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument'],
  'receive_date' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'contribution_page_id' => $contribution_page_id,
  'contribution_status_id' => 'Pending',
  'contribution_source' => ...,
  'line_items' => [
      [
          'params' => $params,
          'line_item' => [
              [
                  'entity_table' => 'civicrm_membership',
                  'price_field_id' => $price_field_value[0]['price_field_id'],
                  'price_field_value_id' => $price_field_value[0]['id'],
                  'qty' => '1',
                  'unit_price' => $total_amount,
                  'line_total' => $total_amount,
              ]
          ]
      ]
  ]
];

$order = civicrm_api3('Order', 'create', $order_data);
```

And like this for the payment:

```
return civicrm_api3('Payment', 'create', [
  'contribution_id' => $contribution_id,
  'total_amount' => $total_amount,
  'trxn_id' => $trxn_id,
  'trxn_date' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'receipt_date' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
  'payment_instrument_id' => $settings['civicrm_contribution_payment_instrument'],
  'is_send_contribution_notification' => 0,
]);
```

Once the payment is passed, I can see the completed Contribution linked to the Membership, but the Membership remains as Pending. Am I missing something?

I am having similar difficulties with updating Memberships: when I enter an existing membership in the params array, it stays as expired after payment. Could it be that both problems are related?

Comment: Can you confirm if contribution is linked with membership? Do you see related contribution when viewing membership?

Comment: @PradeepNayak Yes, and it indicates that the contribution is paid.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a partial solution in this thread: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=13921.0.html

I fixed the issue by changing the Pending status' weight so that it appears further down the list (as in the default settings). However, I am still having an issue with Expired memberships not having their end date changed after an order is created and a payment is passed.

Comment: do you have the required Scheduled Job running?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Yes, I ran it manually and it works for every other type of membership status change.

Comment: is it working as expected if you use pure Civi UI rather than your custom plugin? (I don't know WP well so can't guess why you need a custom plugin.)